# How to convert an Image into a QR code in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am trying to convert an image into a QR code and read the qr code to construct back the image. I can place an image in the center of a QR code using qr_flutter but I am unable figure out a way to represent an entire image as a QR code (possibly QR 40). If anyone can help me with this, it will be really helpful.